# How to map over generic collections and create Map

Tags: scala, generics, dictionary, zip, type-parameter

I'm trying to create Map[String, SLAMetricValue[_]] but compiler complains that type parameter for SLAMetricValue is missed.

```
case class SLAMetricValue[MetricQuantity <: squants.Quantity[MetricQuantity] ](amount: BigDecimal, units: UnitOfMeasure[MetricQuantity]) { ... }

object SLAMetricValue{

import SLAMetric._

  def construct(amount: BigDecimal, metricId: SLAMetricId): SLAMetricValue[_ >: Time with TransferRate with PartQuantity with DataAmount with Dimensionless <: Quantity[_ >: Time with TransferRate with PartQuantity with DataAmount with Dimensionless]] =
    metricId match {
      case id if id == Jitter.id => new SLAMetricValue(amount, Milliseconds)
      case id if id == Throughput.id => new SLAMetricValueTest(amount, BitsPerSecond)
      case _ => ... 
   }
}
  val map1 = metrics.zip(1 to metrics.size).map { case (metric, value) => {
     (metric.id.id.toString, SLAMetricValue.construct(BigDecimal(value), metrics.head.id))
  }}
  val metricIdToMetricValue = map1.toMap
```

I have managed to make it works with `zip` but don't know what's the difference and how make it works without `zip`?

```
(1 to metrics.size).zip(metricIdToIndex).toMap
```

Comment: Did you try to specify type parameters for `toMap` explicitly? Like so: `map1.toMap[String, SLAMetricValue[_]]`

Comment: I supposes it starts to complain before when constructing SLAMetricValue  or a Tuple2.  Anyway, I do try this but it didn't worked out.